# How to add multiple user.rules in ufw?

Tags: debian, iptables, firewall, ufw

I know you can add rules one by one. But is there a way to add rules in one go -

For instance, this is how you add rules in ufw in Debian -

```
$ sudo ufw allow 80/tcp 
$ sudo ufw allow 443/tcp 
$ sudo ufw allow  22/udp
```

Now instead of doing it 1 by 1, is there a way to do it all at once ?

I did try -

```
$ sudo ufw allow 80/tcp 443/tcp 22/udp
```

but that didn't work, any ideas ?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your rules directly. Find where your rules are stored - this may differ by OS version.

I run Ubuntu 16.04; my rules are at /etc/ufw/user.rules
Some older versions of Debian store the files at /lib/ufw/user.rules So, check there too.

After you edit the file, run `sudo ufw reload` to reload the rules.
Then, run `sudo ufw status` to confirm that your new rules have been included.